# Using if statements stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing something where I need to store if statements in a mysql database. I need to pull these statements and use them, each one is an algorithm that I'm testing. I know you can store an if statement in a variable like "$abc = $x > 1 && $f == 1;" and if you run if($abc) {} it will work, I figured I could do the same here, but when I run if($abc) with $abc being an if statement from the database it's not working, it's running the code within the if statement because $abc exists. Code is as follows...

```
$getAlgorithms = mysqli_query($mysql_connect, "SELECT * FROM `algorithms2`");
 while($algorithms = mysqli_fetch_array($getAlgorithms)) {
  $algorithmID = $algorithms['id'];
  $algorithm = $algorithms['algorithm'];
   if($algorithm) { 
    echo("HELLO WORLD");
   }  
}
```

dummy example of what $algorithms['algorithm']; would pull: $r >= $var_x && $z <= $var_y && $lz >= $var_c

I'd really appreciate the help, this is very important. If you have any questions please ask.

NOTE: This is a 100% internal platform

Comment: Hi, can you try with json_encode() and json_decode(). While storing the data, usejson_encode() and while retrieving the data use json_decode()

Comment: If it's not user-supplied formulas, you're basically looking for `eval("return $algo;")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to make use of `eval()` to work as-is:

```
$getAlgorithms = mysqli_query($mysql_connect, "SELECT * FROM `algorithms2`");
 while($algorithms = mysqli_fetch_array($getAlgorithms)) {
  $algorithmID = $algorithms['id'];
  $algorithm = $algorithms['algorithm'];
   if(eval("return {$algorithm};")) { 
    echo("HELLO WORLD");
   }  
}
```

However, executing arbitrary code from an external source (the database) is potentially a horrible security risk: just because you're *expecting* `$algorithm` to be a benign arithmetic expression doesn't mean that it can't be a malicious function call or other statement, for example if someone can enter `system('rm -rf /')` as the algorithm into your database, you're probably going to have a bad day.

Without knowing the precise problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to suggest a better solution, but I'd favour putting the "algorithms" in an array or other hard-coded data-structure within your code rather than the database, it's far safer as anyone who can alter that list can already execute arbitrary code.

For further reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: I believe eval() is the solution, note this is a 100% internal platform, no outside access.

Comment: Also, I can't put them in arrays, it's about 8mm statements/"algorithms", kills performance

Comment: Hah, true enough, PHP array handling is notoriously slow. A hard-coded list or a white-list of acceptable expressions was only a suggestion for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but note that it is especially dangerous to use if there's any chance someone besides you will be creating the strings. There is probably a better, safer way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: It's 100% completely internal, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I believe that is the answer will accept when testing is complete, it runs through about 8mm*10k*130ish statements

Comment: I had to accept Sam's answer because he included a full code sample so future users understand

Answer (score 0):

Store the `If` condion  in your db as string. And then execute it using `eval()` php function .

usage

```
   mixed eval ( string $code )
```

[PHP eval documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)